# How do I create a transparent jumbotron with Bootstrap v. 4.0.0?

Tags: html, css

I've searched through the internet and haven't found any solution for the newest version of bootstrap.

I've thought of two things: Using opacity (didn't work since every other element from the Jumbotron inherits it), and setting a background image whose opacity I thought I could change later (which actually just faded from original to white, still not getting any transparency).

Is there a simple way to do this?

EDIT:
A part of my HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron">

  <h1 class="display-3 text-right">name</h1>

  <hr class="my-4 text-right">
    <p class="lead text-right">description</p>
  <p class="lead text-right">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
  </p>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the background for Jumbotron as `none` to achieve the transparent Jumbotron.

```
.jumbotron {
    background: none
}
```

You can see the complete code at https://gist.github.com/AkashShivanand/7c1ee3fdc578844f3b3dab111d63f0be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="How to create Transparent Jumbotron with Bootstrap V.4.0.0">
    <meta name="author" content="akashshivanand.com">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">
    <title>Transparent Jumbotron with Bootstrap V.4.0.0</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            padding-top: 5rem;            /* Provide Space from Top */
            background: #942626;          /* Set background color for body to justify transparency of Jumbotron */
        }

        .jumbotron {
            background: none;             /* Transparent background */
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <main role="main" class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1 class="display-3 text-right">name</h1>
            <hr class="my-4 text-right">
            <p class="lead text-right">description</p>
            <p class="lead text-right">
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </main>
    <!-- /.container -->
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: for me it didn't work unless using  background: none !important; 

...just saying in case someone struggles with the same in the future.

Comment: Please make sure that `background: none` is placed at the bottom of all the css, then you won't be needing !important. If it doesn't help, would it be possible for you to share your codes or the where where where you have implemented this so that I can help you.

Answer (score 8):

**This could help**

```
.jumbotron {
    background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could just add *bg-transparent* in your html

```
<div class="jumbotron bg-transparent">
  ... 
</div>
```